# total number of hits lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am running a program in Lucene. I get the total number of hits for each word. This means that it gets all the files containing the word I search for.

Example:

```
Searching for 'Amazon'
Number of hits: 2
Hit: Files\peru.txt
Hit: Files\correspondent.txt
Searching for 'business'
Number of hits: 5
Hit: Files\innovation.txt
Hit: Files\xmas.txt
Hit: Files\bp.txt
Hit: Files\symbian.txt
Hit: Files\peru.txt
Searching for 'environment'
Number of hits: 3
Hit: Files\food.txt
Hit: Files\sarkozy.txt
Hit: Files\symbian.txt
```

My First question is how to add the total number of hits for the whole query (2+5+3) and display them them.

My Second question is how to display the results in order ? from 2 then 3 then 5

Any suggestions would be thankful !!

Code for Searching the index and the above output:

```
public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
        int counter = 0 ;



        System.out.println("Searching for '" + searchString + "'");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(FIELD_CONTENTS, analyzer);
        Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
        Hits hits = indexSearcher.search(query);
        System.out.println("Number of hits: " + hits.length());



        Iterator<Hit> it = hits.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Hit hit = it.next();
            Document document = hit.getDocument();
            String path = document.get(path1);
            System.out.println("Hit: " + path);
        }

    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Searcher.search`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) to get the `TopDocs` for each keyword, then sum/sort by the member [`TopDocs.totalHits`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.html#totalHits).

The second parameter to `search` shouldn't matter if you just want statistics. If you want to find all hits, then set it to the number of documents in your index, since that's a trivial upper bound on the number of hits.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the code. could you tell me how can I elaborate this to my requirement ?

Comment: @HumamShbib: it seems you are using the Lucene 2.x API. `TopDocs.totalHits` was `Hits.length()` in that API. I assume you know how to sum or sort a list?

Comment: I do not have any idea I tried using a counter which did not do anything. Could you please tell me how to sum up the hits from Hits.length of each document? and sort the total in an Acsending manner.

Comment: @HumamShbib: for summing, use `+`, for sorting, implement `java.util.Comparator` and use `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: I could not figure it out. Could u copy the code and show me how ? I would really apprecaite it.